# How can i adjust the height of an element to fit the screen when the keyboard is active on iPad?

Tags: ipad, safari, keyboard, overlay

When clicking on a button on my page i open up an overlay with a real-time-editor.
The overlay exactly fills the whole screen.

Now when i click inside the overlay to type something in, the keyboard opens up as expected.
I would like to adjust the size (height) of the overlay so that the keyboard does not lay over parts of my editor, which it unfortunaetly does.

**What can i do to implement this? Is this even possible?**

Edit: I can set the overlay heigth to `(window.innerHeight/3)*2`, which gives me the heigth i would like the overlay to adjust to automatically when the keyboard opens.
Important is that i want this functionality working on my website (web application). So i can use javascript only and no MAC OS specific code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spocke from Moxiecode said this:

> The problem here is that Apple didn't manage to get scrolling working
>   inside a iframe so the "fixed it" by increasing any editable iframe.
>   Overflow and scrolling on iDevices is a pain to handle.

And this is what i found out during my own researches. **It is not possible!**